# Change name of audio file downloaded from youtube-dl

Tags: bash, shell, filenames, wav, youtube-dl

I am writing a shell script to download audio.

> I used `youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' <myurl>` 
> The resulting file is the title along with`-mSc76Q90C4.m4a` where m4a is the format

I would like to set the filename during download and also have it in .wav format

PS: To covert to .wav, I tried `youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio[ext=wav]' <myurl>`  but it did not seem to work. Error thrown is basically - cannot use specified format.

Here is the relavent part of my shell script

```
   `read -p "Copy and paste the YouTube url" URL
    echo $URL
    read -p "Enter the song name" SONG
    youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' $URL`
```

> I would like the string in $SONG to be the filename.

So if `$SONG = "mysongname"`
I want the file to be `mysongname.wav`

Comment: `.m4a` and `.wav` are different audio formats so you'll need to use an audio program for doing the conversion. It's like saying that you got a `.jpg` file but you want it as a `.pdf`; they're not the same thing.

Comment: Yes. That's not really the issue here. I want to change the the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme) of `youtube-dl` you'll find a [`--output`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#filesystem-options) option that lets you set the filename directly:

```sh
youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' -o "$SONG" "$URL"
```

There's also a [`--audio-format`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#post-processing-options) option that seems to convert the extracted audio stream from a video to a given audio format but I'm not sure that it'll work for non-video files.